# Is it possible that for two positive integers i and j, (-i)/j is not equal to -(i/j)?

Tags: c, math

Is it possible that for two positive integers i and j, (-i)/j is not equal to -(i/j) ? I can't figure out if this is possible...i thought it would be something regarding bits, or overflow of a char type or something but i can't find it. Any ideas?

Comment: It could be me, but in `(-i)/j`, `i` looks suspiciously **not**-positive.

Comment: If using signed integers, this wont happen with positive integers. The only funny bit could be when using INT_MIN (least negative integer) and negating on that.

Comment: @WhozCraig The positive integers are `i` and `j`. In the example `i` is negated.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen Yeah, I know. it was the immediate irony of the presentation which I was mulling. And I concur with leppie. This falls on its face when `i = INT_MIN`, but outside of that, I can't see it ever happening, or I'm just not far enough out of the box.

Comment: Could be a problem with integers that don't fit into signed type. For example with `i = 1 << 31` and `j = 2` I get different results.

Comment: @aragaer On my rig, anyway, that would be `INT_MIN` on 32-bit signed integer (sign bit lit, nothing else), which falls into leppie's assessment of the inability to compliment INT_MIN to a positive number, and therefore its fail for that one value.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Pre-C99, it's possible because division of negative operands is implementation-defined; it can be algebraic division or round-towards-zero. C99 defines it to round-towards-zero.

For example, C89 allows `(-1)/2 == -1`, while C99 requires `(-1)/2 == 0`. In all cases, `-(1/2) == 0`.

Comment: +1 (and I wish I could up-vote this more than once) I had no idea it was implementation defined prior to C99)

Comment: Thanks, i actually found this independently but this confirms it. appreciate the responses gentlemen.

Comment: @user1909464: why did you not select this answer? I would encourage you in general to select answers when you get a reply that solves the issue.

Comment: whoops wasn't aware, gotcha

Answer (score 3):

It is indeed **possible when using unsigned integers to represent i and j** (you said positive integers, right? :P).

For instance, the output of the following program is `(-i)/j 2147483647 -(i/j) 0` in my Intel 64bit OSX machine (unsigned ints are 32 bits long)

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
  unsigned int i = 1;
  unsigned int j = 2;
  printf("(-i)/j %u -(i/j) %u\n", (-i)/j, -(i/j));

  return 0;
}
```

Looking at the assembler, the `negl` intel instruction is used to compute the the negation. `negl` performs a [twos complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). The twos complement result, when interpreted as an unsigned value, causes the mismatch. But don't simply take my word for it, here's an example:

For instance, assuming 8bit words, and for i=1 and j=2

In binary form: i=00000001 j=00000010

-(i/j) = twos_complement(00000001/00000010) = twos_complement(00000000) = 00000000

-(i)/j = twos_complement(00000001)/00000010 = 11111111 / 00000001 = 1111111  (127 in decimal)

The mismatch triggered by an unsigned representation even happens when using a C99 compiler. As @R states, another mismatch could also happen in a pre-c99 compiler since the [division by a negative number was implementation defined](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3604984/1914440).

Comment: Use of the phrase "twos complement" is a bit misleading since unary negation of an unsigned argument is not "twos complement", just reduction modulo `UINT_MAX+1`. But nice catch. I hadn't considered the case that OP might be concerned about unsigned types.